# Will I be charged for Amazon API Gateway requests that failed basic request validation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-billing

As per API Gateway documentation, it can perform the following basic request validations:

- The required request parameters in the URI, query string, and headers of an incoming request are included and non-blank.
- The applicable request payload adheres to the configured JSON schema request model of the method.

When the validation fails, API Gateway immediately fails the request, returns a 400 error response to the caller.

I know that I am not charged for:

- Calling methods with the authorization type of AWS_IAM, CUSTOM, and COGNITO_USER_POOLS are not charged for authorization and authentication failures.
- Calls to methods that require API keys are not charged when API keys are missing or invalid.
- API Gateway-throttled requests are not charged when the request rate or burst rate exceeds the preconfigured limits.
- Usage plan-throttled requests are not charged when rate limits or quota exceed the preconfigured limits.

But what I don't understand and cannot find it anywhere on AWS pages if I will be charged for the request to API Gateway if any of the basic validations mentioned in the beginning fail. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: Hi , where in the documentation does it have your “I am not charged for:” bullets?  I feel like they were removed from documentation because I can’t find it anymore.